# Right way to "bump" a question

Tags: discussion

A question I posted some time ago went unanswered. I forgot about the problem (or rather lived with it until now) and would like to tackle it again.

[Cmd + Opt + F stopped working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252498/cmd-opt-f-stopped-working)

What would be the StackExchange way of re-inviting answers?